# Create XML file dynamically in Iphone

Tags: iphone, xml, file

I want to create a xml file dynamically for my Iphone application. I tried it by using NSXMLDocument but NSXMLDocument is not declared in iphone application.

Please help me in doing so.

Thanks

Gaurav

Answer (score 3):

Try the open source [XML stream writer for iOS](http://code.google.com/p/xswi/):

- Written in Objective-C, a single .h. and .m file
- One @protocol for namespaces support and one for without

Example:

```
// allocate serializer
XMLWriter* xmlWriter = [[XMLWriter alloc]init];

// start writing XML elements
[xmlWriter writeStartElement:@"Root"];
[xmlWriter writeCharacters:@"Text content for root element"];
[xmlWriter writeEndElement];

// get the resulting XML string
NSString* xml = [xmlWriter toString];
```

This produces the following XML string:

```
<Root>Text content for root element</Root>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [KissXML](http://code.google.com/p/kissxml/) to generate XML files on the iPhone.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [libxml2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1822131/iphone-xmlrequest/1822804#1822804) to generate XML data on the iPhone.