# How to save and update value in xml file in iOS?

Tags: ios

In iOS, I am reading a xml file. Here I want to write the xml file and I want to change the values of the XML file and I want to save the file.

My code is like below... Please guide me how to save and update value in xml file.

```
-(void)writexmlfile:(NSString *)data toFile:(NSString *)fileName nodename:(NSString *)nodename{


    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    // the path to write file
    NSString *appFile = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.xml",fileName]];
    BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:appFile];
    if(fileExists) {
        NSError *error = nil;
        NSString *docStr;
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

        // the path to write file
        NSString *appFile = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.xml",fileName]];

        BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:appFile];
        if(fileExists)
        {
            NSLog(@"file exist in document");
            NSData *myData1 = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:appFile];
            if (myData1) {  
                docStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:myData1 encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

            } 
        }
        NSMutableString *str = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        NSString *aaa=[NSString stringWithFormat:@" <%@>%@</%@>",nodename,data,nodename];
        [str appendString:docStr];

        [str insertString:aaa atIndex:70];
        BOOL success = [str writeToFile:appFile  atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
        if (!success) {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error userInfo]);
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"File write is successful");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In short,

1. use an XML parser to read the XML
2. represent the XML in some kind of object structure (data binding)
3. modify the object structure; this is where you insert your new elements etc
4. use an XML serializer to write the XML (making your own XML is not recommended) from the object structure

In steps 1 and 4 you either go via NSData or read directly from file, depending on the XML parser and writer API.

You can use NSXMLParser to parse the XML, and libxml(2) to writer, alternatively other readers and [writers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825605/create-xml-file-dynamically-in-iphone) ([this one](http://code.google.com/p/xswi/) by me).

Answer (score 1):

Use libxml2 dylib available in the xcode links library sections and use xmlwriter class for creating your xml files. 
sample code

```
xmlTextWriterPtr _writer;
xmlBufferPtr _buf;
xmlChar *xmlString;
const char *_UTF8Encoding = "UTF-8";

_buf = xmlBufferCreate();
_writer = xmlNewTextWriterMemory(_buf, 0);

// <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
xmlTextWriterStartDocument(_writer, "1.0", _UTF8Encoding, NULL);

xmlTextWriterStartElement(_writer, BAD_CAST "root");

    // <request type="handle" action="update">
xmlTextWriterStartElement(_writer, BAD_CAST "child");

xmlString = [self xmlCharPtrForInput:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",objPatient.strFname] cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] withEncoding:_UTF8Encoding];
xmlTextWriterWriteAttribute(_writer, BAD_CAST "fname", BAD_CAST xmlString);

xmlTextWriterEndElement(_writer);//Close child
xmlTextWriterEndElement(_writer); //close root here
```

The method xmlcharptrforinput is,

```
- (xmlChar *) xmlCharPtrForInput:(const char *)_input withEncoding:(const char *)_encoding 
{
    xmlChar *_output;
    int _ret;
    int _size;
    int _outputSize;
    int _temp;
    xmlCharEncodingHandlerPtr _handler;

    if (_input == 0)
        return 0;

    _handler = xmlFindCharEncodingHandler(_encoding);

    if (!_handler) {
        //NSLog(@"convertInput: no encoding handler found for '%s'\n", (_encoding ? _encoding : ""));
        return 0;
    }

    _size = (int) strlen(_input) + 1;
    _outputSize = _size * 2 - 1;
    _output = (unsigned char *) xmlMalloc((size_t) _outputSize);

    if (_output != 0) {
        _temp = _size - 1;
        _ret = _handler->input(_output, &_outputSize, (const xmlChar *) _input, &_temp);
        if ((_ret < 0) || (_temp - _size + 1)) {
            if (_ret < 0) {
                //NSLog(@"convertInput: conversion wasn't successful.\n");
            } else {
                //NSLog(@"convertInput: conversion wasn't successful. Converted: %i octets.\n", _temp);
            }   
            xmlFree(_output);
            _output = 0;
        } else {
            _output = (unsigned char *) xmlRealloc(_output, _outputSize + 1);
            _output[_outputSize] = 0;  //null terminating out
        }
    } else {
        //NSLog(@"convertInput: no memory\n");
    }

    return _output;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the both the Mac OS X and iOS platforms, you can use the NSUserDefaults class for saving to and reading from .plist which is XML formatted property list. Your Xcode project itself uses such property list for example Info.plist. 
One additional benefits of using NSDefaults is it supports serialization of Objective-C objects so in essence you're saving and reading binary data.

Hope this helps, and good luck.

If this answer helps you, please mark your question as answered, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

i suggest that u see link which is given to below:
http://reecon.wordpress.com/2010/04/09/reading-from-xml-file-in-objective-c/
and see also 
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/iPhone/iPhoneXMLParser.aspx
if u not getting sufficient solution then give comment i will give another solution.

Answer (score 0):

Since the iPhone doesn't really have a DOM parser (No NSXmlDocument) I suggest using a third party parser. My favorite is GDataXMLNode from Google. [GDataXMLNode](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/source/browse/#svn/trunk/Source/XMLSupport)

Answer (score 0):

Use [GDataXMLNode Objective-C library](https://github.com/flagman/GDataXMLNode/blob/master/Classes/GDataXMLNode.m)

For [XML parsing and writing tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/725/xml-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-read-and-write-xml-documents-with-gdataxml)

#### You can update like this for example in Swift 3.0 > :

```
do {
     let contactXMLDocument : GDataXMLDocument = try GDataXMLDocument(xmlString: strXMLData)
     let entryElement:GDataXMLElement = contactXMLDocument.rootElement()
     //remove first
     if let arrNameElements:Array<GDataXMLElement> = entryElement.elements(forName: "gd:name") as? Array<GDataXMLElement>{
         for nameElement:GDataXMLElement in arrNameElements {
            entryElement.removeChild(nameElement)
         }
      }
      //now add
      let nameElement : GDataXMLElement = GDataXMLNode.element(withName: "gd:name")
      //Other child to names
      //add name to entry
      entryElement.addChild(nameElement)

     //Generate Data
     let contactXMLData:Data = contactXMLDocument.xmlData()
     if let strUpdatedContactXML : String = String(data: contactXMLData, encoding: .utf8) 
     {
        print("Updated ContactXML : \(strUpdatedContactXML)")
        //save file here if needed
     }
}
catch {
        
}
```