# How can I write this XML example to an XML file?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xml

How do I write this so it will be saved in an XML file?

```
<Stations>
    <station id="1">
        <title>Lehavim Railway station</title>
        <latitude>31.369834</latitude>
        <longitude>34.798207</longitude>
    </station>
</Stations>
```

I have this part of code, but I don't know how to arrange it so that it will be saved as shown above.

```
    NSArray * paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, 
                                                          NSUserDomainMask, 
                                                          YES);

    NSString * filePath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    filePath = [filePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"favorite"];
    filePath = [filePath stringByAppendingPathExtension:@"xml"];

    NSDictionary *station = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                              @"Lehavim Railway station",
                              @"31.369834",
                              @"34.798207",
                              , nil  ];

    [station writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
```

I also don't know how to change the `id` in the station part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the local iOS file system, XML files look the same as the [plist files](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man5/plist.5.html) written out by NSDictionary or NSArray so programmers can frequently "cheat" (or take a short cut?) by writing out nested dictionaries or arrays and considering them XML files.

Except these files are not XML.  And you can't write out XML-style attributes (i.e. the `id = "1"` bit in your example up there) via the standard NSDictionary or NSArray `writeToFile:` methods.

You need to decide on a class that creates XML objects and allows you to write them out.

[Here is a related question with a selection of answers & choices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825605/create-xml-file-dynamically-in-iphone) that can help you figure out the right way to go.  For my own projects, I really like [libxml2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1822131/iphone-xmlrequest/1822804#1822804).