# Sync iPhone application local database on to remote desk

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I have make an transaction application.

I insert transaction data into local SQLITE database table.

Now i want to sync this database and save it on desktop.

How can i make it? If any idea or reference will be nice to implement it.

Thanks

Comment: Implement web services where you will send data in form of xml to server..

Answer (score 0):

You can use web services to send data to server.

The approach will be to have a service hosted on your server (in any programming language)  where you will take data from sqlite, create its xml/json, and sends data in either XML/json format to server. Here your server will parse xml and store data in your database server.

Hope this info helps you..

Sample of web service creation

http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/ws_example.asp

For creating XML in iPhone, you can see [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825605/create-xml-file-dynamically-in-iphone)