# Transforming Core Data info into XML and vice versa

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, core-data, nsxmlparser

I have my application talking to a server. What I need to do is pull information from the Core Data persistent store and parse it to XML, then send it to the server. The server will respond in XML and I will need to parse this back to Core Data.

What is the best way to do this? I'm aware of `NSXMLParser` but unfortunately I haven't found any good tutorials on how to use it for my application.

Edit: There are so many better things than NSXMLParser now. Check SO for more answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as writing your data out as XML goes, you'll probably find [this Stackoverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1822131/iphone-xmlrequest/1822804#1822804) helpful.

Sending the data back and forth can be done using an [`NSURLConnection`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html) with a custom delegate.

Retrieving the data from the XML can be done using `NSXMLParser`, like you said.