# How to write XML file with data from text fields

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xml, uitextfield

I am creating a project in which I have three `UITextField`s and one `UIButton`. Now on text fields I have function that user give input. I define a target-action on button press which needs to save the values of the text fields in an XML file. How do I create an xml file and save all the data in xml file with unique ID?

```
-(IBAction)Submit:(id)sender{
    if([txtPhone.text length] == 0 || [txtPhone.text isEqualToString:@""] && [txtName.text length] == 0 || [txtName.text isEqualToString:@""] && [txtEmail.text length] == 0 || [txtEmail.text isEqualToString:@""] )
    {
        UIAlertView *info = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Info" message: @"Please fill the form." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [info show];
        [info release]; 
    }
    else {
        sixthView=[[SixthView alloc] initWithNibName:@"SixthView" bundle:nil];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.sixthView animated:YES];
        self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:nil action:nil] autorelease];
    }
}
```

Comment: i have define a code of action of button. here i want save data in xml file. This question not similar to any one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XSWI project hosts a simple, **standalone XML stream writer for iOS implemented in Objective-C**. 
As such, it can be used for iPhone, iPad and iPod apps.

you could get the source code  from [github project](https://github.com/skjolber/xswi).

check the SO post for [creating an XML request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1822131/iphone-xmlrequest/1822804#1822804) in iPhone.

Comment: how i use these file in  my projects?

Comment: use the link http://code.google.com/p/xswi/downloads/list to download and use the XMLWriter class.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to use XML? I recommend you to use CSV, its simpler and then export a CSV to iTunes. I have posted a code in my blog here about how to export a file to iTunes http://alwawee.com/wordpress/?p=429. To generate unique name you can use current date in addition to some file name or use id, that is stored in NSUserDefaults.

Comment: If you want to get used to XML in iPhone try reading this http://dblog.com.au/general/iphone-sdk-tutorial-building-an-advanced-rss-reader-using-touchxml-part-1/. It helped me a lot. Also I recommend you to use this library: TBXML http://www.tbxml.co.uk/TBXML/TBXML_Free.html It is very simple and nice.