# i have xml file in my application that i want to write data into it

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xml-parsing

I have this xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Favorites>
    <favorite id="1">
        <title>My first favorite</title>
        <latitude>31.369834</latitude>
        <longitude>34.798207</longitude>
    </favorite>
</Favorites>
```

and I want to write more "favorite"s into it.
I have all the data I need as strings in my project.
But I can't figure out how to really do it - although I have tried a lot.

can you please help me do it ?
thanks.

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1822131/iphone-xmlrequest/1822804#1822804

Comment: If you don't have some external requirement for using XML, Alex Nichol's suggestion is a good one. You could also use JSON, since iOS includes APIs for creating and reading JSON (as of iOS5).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with the responders that you should consider using a .plist file.  Creating NSDictionary objects of your "Favorite" objects, and saving the array of them.

But, to your immediate question, you could save a NSString representing your XML like this (but again, saving a string based XML means a lot of parsing and interaction methods created by you):

```
// Build The Path
//
NSArray * paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, 
                                                      NSUserDomainMask, 
                                                      YES);

NSString * filePath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

filePath = [filePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"favorites"];
filePath = [filePath stringByAppendingPathExtension:@"xml"];


// You Should Have A "Favorite" Objects That Know How To Desribe Themselves...
//
NSString * badWayToDoThis = @"<ThinkAboutUsingDictionaries>Saving The Data to a plist</seriously>";

[badWayToDoThis writeToFile:filePath 
                 atomically:YES 
                   encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding 
                      error:NULL];
```

Hope that at the very least gets you towards where you're headed.

Comment: Hi, first of all thank you,
i understand what you have told me here- but can't understand this - 
`code`// You Should Have A "Favorite" Objects That Know How To Desribe Themselves...

Comment: You say you have all the data as strings in your project.  To that end the data should be strings stored in a NSObject for each "Favorite" item.  Inside that object should be a method that returns the data of the object in the form you need (NSDictionary, NSString, etc).   -In the case of the above example you could override the NSOBject's 'description' method to return a string.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a plist and create functions that:

```
First - creates an array or dictionary from the plist
Second - adds new values to your array/dictionary 
Third - saves the dictionary to the same file, overwriting and updating the old version.
```

So rather that inserting values you just overwrite with an updated version